# Magento 1.9.1 - Emails being sent by the new email queue?

Tags: email, queue

According to the [Magento 1.9.1 release notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce-19-1910-patches):

> all Magento e-mails (including order confirmation and transactional) are now queued

However, I cannot see how any emails except the new order and order update emails are being queued.

In [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45916/magento-ce-1-9-1-not-using-cron-for-sending-emails/52478#52478) you can see the only two places that appear to use the queue.

Am I missing something obvious that would have the queue instantiated for emails such as the contact form POST in `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`?

I cannot see anything, which makes me think the release notes are wrong, someone please show me the error of my ways?

Answer (score 2):

I tested it on clean Magento 1.9.0.1 installation without setup cron job and it sent me a contact email. So it's not queue contact emails. And if you look at the code you will see the same:

`Mage_Contacts_IndexController` -> `public function postAction()` -> `sendTransactional` which calls:

`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` -> `public function sendTransactional` -> `public function send` -> `$mail->send();`.

On deeper level it calls `Zend_Mail` -> `public function send` -> `$transport->send($this);` -> `Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract` -> `public function send` -> `$this->_sendMail();` -> `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail` -> `public function _sendMail()` which finally calls directly PHP `mail()` function:

```
    $result = mail(
        $this->recipients,
        $this->_mail->getSubject(),
        $this->body,
        $this->header);
```

---

In Magento 1.9.1.0 it's added

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
...
$emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();
```

in 
`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` -> `public function send` which should be set in `public function sendTransactional`:

```
        if (is_numeric($templateId)) {
            $queue = $this->getQueue();
            $this->load($templateId);
            $this->setQueue($queue);
        }
```

but `$templateId` should be equal to `contacts_email_email_template` (by default) so it's not numeric. But if custom email template is chosen it will be numeric so maybe then the email will be queued but I didn't test it.

Comment: I think OP mentioned 1.9.1 release.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have 1.9.1 installation (and I don't have time to install it) and I thought that there isn't much difference (but clearly I was wrong). I edited my answer but I didn't test it so some moderator can delete my answer if it's not useful.

Comment: I think the is_numeric test is just to handle restoring the queue to the template object after loading a custom template. It still requires the Queue to have been already set, and I do not see anywhere that is happening except in the Order email sending functions.