# Non-transactional emails are not being sent (email confirmation, welcome email, shipping)

Tags: email, magento1.9.2.4

I've looked at the core-email queue in the SQL database and only "new order" and "update order" are being sent in the queue for the CRON job.

I've read somewhere that there might be an exception and that only transaction-email are being sent to the queue and the rest is being handle by the server.
[Magento 1.9.1 - Emails being sent by the new email queue?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52479/magento-1-9-1-emails-being-sent-by-the-new-email-queue)

So, I found this guide to see how to debug it 
http://www.hummingbirduk.com/magento-not-sending-emails/ 
and followed the steps and was able to see receive test emails from the server. So the problem lies in the magento configuration and settings.

I've been spending quite some time figuring the problem and now I am out of idea and was wondering if someone my have hints about how to solve this problem or what step could I take to narrow the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New order email confirmation not being sent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent)

Answer (score 0):

**1-**

A CRON is a daemon which keeps running and gets activated at a said interval (time period). Cron helps store owners to setup up and schedule commands which will run periodically at set time and date. Various Magento services such as “Sending Newsletter “, Cleanup with logs, Cleanup cache, Customer notification etc. requires a mechanism where store owners can setup and schedule commands to run periodically.

Most of the web hosts have their own set of task scheduler; you can ask and verify the task scheduler from your webhost. While setting a cron-job make sure that minimum time duration is set to run every 15 minutes (not less than this) as  Magento spends around 1 minute to index 1000 products and sets the status to “Success” from “Pending”.

Now to setup Crontab in Magento go to **`Admin => system => configuration => system => ‘Cron (Scheduled Tasks)’ tab.`**

You will notice that all times are in minutes.

**Magento Cron Best Practices**

```
Generate schedules every: 60

Schedule ahead for: 1

Missed if not run within: 60

History cleanup every: 120

Success history lifetime: 120

Failure history lifetime: 120
```

run the cron every 15 minutes for better results and that will not overlap with other Cron services.

**2-**

go to your hosting cpanel and set path and run time of cron.php file in cron job section

by default you can set path like `php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I route my transaction e-mails to Mandrill. Allowing me to see exactly what my store is sending.

If you don't have a paid Mailchimp account. You can get SendGrid that has similar (and free) e-mailing services.

In Mandrill's dashboard, I can see which e-mail is being sent, Delivery of the e-mail & when it is being sent.

You can drop an easy extension into your CE setup to set it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Send your transactional email through [Pepipost](http://www.pepipost.com/) using Magento I recommend the "SMTP Pro Email - Free Custom SMTP Email" free extension. Once installed you need to change at least the following options:

- Authentication - Login
- Username - Your_Pepipost_Username
- Password - Your_Pepipost_Password
- Host - smtp.pepipost.com
- Port - 587
- SSL Security -SSL TLS

Ref: http://support.pepipost.com/knowledge_base/topics/magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Since **Magento 1.9.1**, the emails are not being sent **directly** during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob.

There were some changes to email in **Magento 1.9.1** from the Magento 1.9.1 release notes. Two things jump out as requiring further investigation:

> “all Magento e-mails (including order confirmation and transactional)
>   are now queued and sent according to your configured cron schedule”
>
> “boasts responsive default email templates so customers can read your order confirmation emails and newsletters on any device”

I suggest you to install this free extension [SMTP Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html), set the SMTP config  connexion like Gmail for exemple, and **dont forget** to set `Queue Usage` to `never`, save and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file called "mail.php" and add it to `/pub/` so it's accessible via browser. (Eg. http://www.example.com/mail.php)

In the file, add:

```
<?php var_dump(mail('info@example.com', 'info@example.com', 'info@example.com'));
```

- If you see `bool(false)`, something fatal has gone wrong and it is
  best submitting a support ticket with your hosting provider.
- If you see `bool(true)` displayed on screen but no email in your
  inbox, it is likely SPF or DKIM.
- If you see `bool(true)` displayed on screen and an email in your
  inbox confirms that PHP is sending emails.
- If you see `bool(true)` displayed on screen and an email in your
  inbox, but you still don't see your emails from Magento, its likely
  Magento is misconfigured.