# Send all emails with cron/queue

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, email-scheduler, queue

I'm using magento 1.9.3.6 and I've read that from magento 1.9.1 supposedly all emails were going to be queued, however only the order/invoice/order-update emails appear affected. I can't find an exact reason but I assume it was reversed or stated in error. Please see here if curious:
http://www.aschroder.com/2015/01/sending-emails-by-queue-in-magento-1-9-1/
[Magento 1.9.1 - Emails being sent by the new email queue?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52479/magento-1-9-1-emails-being-sent-by-the-new-email-queue)

I'd like to send all emails with the queue so they go through the Mailchimp/Mandrill extension I'm using.

Is there an elegent way to handle this that doesn't include overwriting every send/sendMail method that the contact form and other extensions use?

Comment: Does your cron setup correctly?

Comment: @Hit's Yes it's setup and running fine. It sends queued emails(orders, invoices, etc.) when the cron runs, through the Mailchimp/Mandrill extension I have setup. However for other emails(contact form, etc) it's sending them immediately with php/magento. I want these all to be queued.

Comment: maybe mandrill can help [you](https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento/issues/722)

Comment: [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52479/magento-1-9-1-emails-being-sent-by-the-new-email-queue) might help you OR go through [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent) one

Comment: @Hit's I contacted the team that makes their Mandrill extension and they wouldn't help.

Comment: @iamlolz, what exact error you are facing currently ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat there is no error, I just want some advice on the best way to go about forcing Magento to queue ALL emails.